# Meteor use tippy.js on two claases/elements

Tags: tooltip, meteor-blaze, tippyjs

I need two tooltips with different content to appear on 4 elements which I have given 2 identical class names.
The html looks like:

```
<sup>
<a href="" class="fas fa-info cs-info"></a>
</sup>
```

and

```
<sup>
<a href="" class="fas fa-info price-info"></a>
</sup>
```

(The above are present twice in the html code)
The javascript

```
Template.stepOne.onRendered(function(){


      tippy('.cs-info', {
        content: "some explanation Info 1",
      });

      tippy('.price-info', {
        content: "some explanation Info 2",
      });
    }
```

when I only use one tippy with one content it appears, the problem is when using the second as well..what is the right way to write it in Meteor Blaze?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to move the javascript code inside template events `'mouseenter..cs-info'` instead of `onRendered`